# Formatting Human Names - PHP (or any language) library?

Tags: php, formatting, string-formatting

Is there a way to format human names? For example, "joHn dOE" should be "John Doe". Or "angus macgyver" should be "Angus MacGyver". etc.

I know that any solution is probably not going to be complete (there's just too many rules to names), but something is better than nothing. Any suggestions?

Comment: You want a capital letter added and the rest lowercase?

Comment: `ucfirst` and a list of affixes would go a long way. The proverbial 20% of effort.

Comment: Don't bother. Either leave it exactly as the user has entered it, or run it through a simple `ucfirst()`.

Comment: In Python: `x = 'joHn dOE'; x.title()` returns `'John Doe'`.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor But i'm sure this is not python

Comment: @DarylGill The title says "any language".

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for a php script that could handle proper capitalization of names.  While I realize that it would be difficult to handle 100% of cases

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_family_name_affixes

I think this script does a pretty good job handling 95% of use cases, at least for us.  It's certainly a great starting point.

http://www.media-division.com/correct-name-capitalization-in-php/

```
function titleCase($string) 
{
    $word_splitters = array(' ', '-', "O'", "L'", "D'", 'St.', 'Mc');
    $lowercase_exceptions = array('the', 'van', 'den', 'von', 'und', 'der', 'de', 'da', 'of', 'and', "l'", "d'");
    $uppercase_exceptions = array('III', 'IV', 'VI', 'VII', 'VIII', 'IX');

    $string = strtolower($string);
    foreach ($word_splitters as $delimiter)
    { 
        $words = explode($delimiter, $string); 
        $newwords = array(); 
        foreach ($words as $word)
        { 
            if (in_array(strtoupper($word), $uppercase_exceptions))
                $word = strtoupper($word);
            else
            if (!in_array($word, $lowercase_exceptions))
                $word = ucfirst($word); 

            $newwords[] = $word;
        }

        if (in_array(strtolower($delimiter), $lowercase_exceptions))
            $delimiter = strtolower($delimiter);

        $string = join($delimiter, $newwords); 
    } 
    return $string; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested in the comments, in PHP, you can do something like this:

```
$name_formatted = ucfirst(strtolower($name_unformatted));
```

This will handle 90% of your cases. I would then put that into a function and add rules to deal with the MacGuyver, O'Reilly type exceptions.

**Update:**
As pointed out, ucfirst only does the first word in a string. You could use regex to uppercase all first letters in every word, or do a function like this:

```
<?php
$name_unformatted = "JOHN DOE";

function format_name($name_unformatted)
{
   $name_formatted = ucwords(strtolower($name_unformatted));  // this will handle 90% of the names

   // ucwords will work for most strings, but if you wanted to break out each word so you can deal with exceptions, you could do something like this:
   $separator = array(" ","-","+","'");
   foreach($separator as $s)
   {
      if (strpos($name_formatted, $s) !== false)
      {
         $word = explode($s, $name_formatted);
         $tmp_ary = array_map("ucfirst", array_map("strtolower", $word));  // whatever processing you want to do here
         $name_formatted = implode($s, $tmp_ary);
      }
   }

   return $name_formatted;
}

echo format_name($name_unformatted);
?>
```

You can expand on this function to handle your name exceptions.

Comment: `ucfirst` wont do anything for JOHN DOE.

Comment: Well yes and no @snoopy76 - my code with lowercase the entire string and then just uppercase the first letter. I will update my answer with a function that will do all words.

Comment: DOH! Forgot about the ucwords function in PHP.

Comment: I see the merits of your function. Though I realize it won't handle every possible case there is for names (since the rules are just exponential), I think it's a great start already. I'm curious about the `+` symbol you used as a word separator. Do you have an example of a name that uses a `+`?

Comment: I grabbed that snippet of code from the php website I think - you could remove the + since it is probably not used in your scenario. Please accept my answer if you find it useful. Thanks!

Comment: I thought this was your code. If you took this from another site, can you please cite the source?

Comment: Following up. Can you please cite your source?

Answer (score 0):

For what concerns italian names I found an easy solution with

```php
function formatName(string $firstName, string $lastName): array
{
    $delimiters = " -’'\t\r\n\f\v";

    return \array_map(
        fn ($string) => \ucwords(\mb_strtolower($string), $delimiters),
        [$firstName, $lastName]
    );
}
```

In my case I had to deal with surnames like `D'Amico`, `De Angelis`, `Di Cataldo` and `Rossi-Bianchi` and this quick solution worked just fine.

The main player is

```
\ucwords(\mb_strtolower($string), $delimiters)
```

the rest is just part of how I dealt with names by dividing first name and last name.